# How to access member value of multidimensional array if name is given as variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to access members of multidimensional array by having name of member as variable? So, one could change column by changing variable value and get the value of that column eventually.

**Example Dataset**

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 2757, 
        "name": "Callisto Network", 
        "symbol": "CLO", 
        "website_slug": "callisto-network", 
        "rank": 472, 
        "circulating_supply": 431731687.0, 
        "total_supply": 479443453.0, 
        "max_supply": 6500000000.0, 
        "quotes": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 0.0183603, 
                "volume_24h": 37051.4, 
                "market_cap": 7926723.0, 
                "percent_change_1h": 0.15, 
                "percent_change_24h": -2.43, 
                "percent_change_7d": -9.42
            }, 
            "BTC": {
                "price": 2.7767e-06, 
                "volume_24h": 5.6034650942, 
                "market_cap": 1199.0, 
                "percent_change_1h": 0.01, 
                "percent_change_24h": -6.16, 
                "percent_change_7d": -7.0
            }
        }, 
        "last_updated": 1531748143
    }, 
    "metadata": {
        "timestamp": 1531747771, 
        "error": null
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example dataset ?

Comment: https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/2757/?convert=BTC

value would be USD or BTC, so once you would need something like
data.quotes.USD.price and other time data.quotes.BTC.price

Question is, how to get these "USD" or "BTC" inside of query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set keys in an array and loop through it to get values dynamically, something like below

```js
var array = {
  "data": {
        "id": 2757, 
        "name": "Callisto Network", 
        "symbol": "CLO", 
        "website_slug": "callisto-network", 
        "rank": 473, 
        "circulating_supply": 431584927.0, 
        "total_supply": 479260453.0, 
        "max_supply": 6500000000.0, 
        "quotes": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 0.0185867, 
                "volume_24h": 37855.1, 
                "market_cap": 8021740.0, 
                "percent_change_1h": 8.15, 
                "percent_change_24h": -2.81, 
                "percent_change_7d": -8.51
            }, 
            "BTC": {
                "price": 2.8148e-06, 
                "volume_24h": 5.7328503345, 
                "market_cap": 1215.0, 
                "percent_change_1h": 7.98, 
                "percent_change_24h": -6.41, 
                "percent_change_7d": -5.96
            }
        }, 
        "last_updated": 1531744663
    }, 
    "metadata": {
        "timestamp": 1531744326, 
        "error": null
    }
};

/* Specifying keys in array */
var key = ["USD", "BTC"];

for (key in array.data.quotes) {    
    /* Price of both keys */
    console.log(key + ' price is: ' + array.data.quotes[key].price);
    /*****************************************/
}
```

Or, you can simply pass the variable name like this

```
var key = "USD";
console.log(array.data.quotes[key].price);
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks for help, it works :)

```
const variable = 'USD' // change it to BTC
alert(JSON.stringify(array.quotes[variable].price), true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use alternative object syntax like this:

```
data.quotes[$variable].price
```

Here is the example with your data [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjy4p6L5/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. On the object that you provided:

```
let myObject = {
    "data": {
        "id": 2757, 
        "name": "Callisto Network", 
        "symbol": "CLO", 
        "website_slug": "callisto-network", 
        "rank": 478, 
        "circulating_supply": 431633647.0, 
        "total_supply": 479321653.0, 
        "max_supply": 6500000000.0, 
        "quotes": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 0.0180211, 
                "volume_24h": 36733.5, 
                "market_cap": 7778513.0, 
                "percent_change_1h": 3.86, 
                "percent_change_24h": -5.71, 
                "percent_change_7d": -11.29
            }, 
            "BTC": {
                "price": 2.7279e-06, 
                "volume_24h": 5.5604246894, 
                "market_cap": 1177.0, 
                "percent_change_1h": 3.77, 
                "percent_change_24h": -9.24, 
                "percent_change_7d": -8.86
            }
        }, 
        "last_updated": 1531744784
    }, 
    "metadata": {
        "timestamp": 1531744413, 
        "error": null
    }
}
```

To access the `name` field from a variable on this object, you would do:

```
let x = 'name'

console.log(myObject.data[name]);
```

Notice instead of using a `.`, we are instead wrapping the variable `name` with an opening and closing bracket to access it.

`"Callisto Network"` would print out

You can learn more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors